# Changing Default Installation Folder of Visual Studio 2005 Setup

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-services, installation

I have created a windows service using Visual Studio 2005. I have created a setup project that would install my application. Now, the default installation folder is always c:\program files\Default Company Name\XXXX.

Where can I change this to be something else on startup. Basically, I want the Default Company Name to be removed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just visit "Application Folder" properties ,here you can view the default location consisting [ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer][ProductName].. Modify according to  your need

Comment: Long time has passed since the question was asked and I no longer have visual stdio 2005 installed, so wasn't able to verify it. Based on readings made elsewhere, I guess this is correct.